# Why i am getting error as "Method must have a first parameter, usually called 'self' " for flask-socket-io connect event

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a live chat app using flask socket-io. But where I use connect event it shows this "**Method must have a first parameter, usually called 'self'** " error. How can I fix this. I am using flask-socketio 4.3.0.
Here is my code.

```
    @socketio.on('disconnect')
    def disconnect():
        print('Client disconnected')

    @socketio.on('connect')
    def connect():
        print("Client connected")
```

here is screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Because flask is written in Python, and [Python instance methods need self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Comment: adding self never executes this line         print('Client disconnected') when user connects or disconnects

Comment: But that is why your IDE is complaining. I would read up on the Flask documentation as to why its methods don't need a `self`.

Comment: Is this just something the IDE is pointing out, or something Python complains about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing an incomplete code example in your question. You are defining these handlers inside a class, not as standalone functions, correct?

The handlers are supposed to be regular functions. If you want to keep them in your class, try making them static methods:

```
    @socketio.on('disconnect')
    @staticmethod
    def disconnect():
        print('Client disconnected')

    @socketio.on('connect')
    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        print("Client connected")
```